# How to modify the sortProperties value dynamically inside an ember.js ArrayController

Tags: ember.js

I'm using ember 1.0 pre and have a basic array controller that starts out with a default sort property of 'id'

```
PersonApp.PersonController = Ember.ArrayController.extend({
  content: [],
  sortProperties: ['id'],
  updateSort: function(column) {
    this.set('sortProperties', column);
  }
});
```

I'd like to set this dynamically and have the dom updated for free. But when I do a simple setter (shown above) it doesn't update anything in my view or on the dom.

If I need the ability to update this dynamically how can I go about it?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The `sortProperties` must be an array, so I don't know if in your case, `column` is one.
Here is a js fiddle showing you dynamically setting it: http://jsfiddle.net/Sly7/jZVJA/22/

Comment: nice! exactly what I was looking for!

Comment: one last question about your usage of this. I noticed you went to the global App to set it but if I'm in the router should I prefer to get this using something like router.get('personController') ?

Comment: yes it's better to access a controller via the router rather than via the App.

Answer (score 1):

This answer does not respond to the original question, but I experienced this symptom and had a different root issue.

In my case, I was changing the `sortProperties` dynamically but this was having no effect on my array of models.  The issue turned out to be that I was reading my backing array from a wrapper method, which failed to observe the `sortProperties`, so even though the `sortProperties` were updating, my template was not redrawing the underlying array.

Updating my wrapper method to observe `sortProperties` directly did the trick.