# Sorting an ArrayController backed by Ember-Data via sortProperty mixin

Tags: ember.js, ember-data

I'd like to be able to sort an `ArrayController` whose content arises from an ember-data query. Unfortunately, the `sortProperty` mixin doesn't seem to work in this case.

I'd like to be able to do the following:

```
App = Ember.Application.create();
App.store = DS.Store.create({ revision: 4});

App.Item = DS.Model.extend({
    id: DS.attr('string'),
    name: DS.attr('string')
});

App.store.createRecord(App.Item, {id: '4', name: 'banana' });
App.store.createRecord(App.Item, {id: '2', name: 'apple'});
App.store.createRecord(App.Item, {id: '6', name: 'spaghetti'}); 

App.ItemsController = Ember.ArrayController.create({
    content: App.store.findAll(App.Item),
    sortProperties: ['name']
});
```

With the latest version of `Ember` and Ember-data, this gives the output:

```
[ id: 4, name: banana ]

[ id: 2, name: apple ]

[ id: 6, name: spaghetti ]
```

The issue here is that `App.store.findAll()` returns a `RecordArray` whose content property is not simply an array of `App.Item` instances (in this case, content is [2, 3, 4])

To actually get my hands on the instances I need to use something like `objectAt()`. But even if I extract the `App.Item` instances from the `RecordArray` and dump them in an ordinary array, things don't work as expected.

Am I missing the obvious way to do this, or is this just the present state of the framework? I'd rather not have to replicate all of my models as plain objects just to sort them.

**EDIT:**

I got around the issue by making my own custom `ArrayController`. Still, it would be nice if things worked as above.

**EDIT #2:**

Original Handlebars template:

```
<script type="text/x-handlebars">
    {{#each App.ItemsController.content }}
        <p>[ id: {{id}}, name: {{name}} ]</p>
    {{/each}}
</script>
```

(Also, I had used a `sortProperty` property instead of `sortProperties` in my code above, but that was just a typo.)

And yes, if one instead uses

```
<script type="text/x-handlebars">
    {{#each App.ItemsController.arrangedContent }}
        <p>[ id: {{id}}, name: {{name}} ]</p>
    {{/each}}
</script>
```

Then we get exactly what we want:

```
[ id: 2, name: apple ]

[ id: 4, name: banana ]

[ id: 6, name: spaghetti ]
```

Comment: I'm sorry, you haven't done a particularly good job of explaining what's not working here, can you please put your handlebars template in. I think there's a small issue where sometimes you have to bind to the `arrangedContent` value of the `ArrayController` to get the correctly ordered objects.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

As of Ember 1.1.2 and ember-data 1.0.0-beta.3, and probably earlier, just setting sortProperties on the Controller is enough. `sortAscending` can be set to `true` or `false` depending on which direction you want to sort.

```
App.ArrayController = Ember.ArrayController.extend({
  sortProperties: ['name'],
  sortAscending: true
})
```

However, note that

```
sortProperties: ['id']
```

appears to sort lexically rather than numerically. I got around the lexical sorting by a created_at timestamp, but there may be another way around it.

Comment: can `sortProperties` be changed dynamically after load? and how do you choose ascending or descending?

Comment: Added in reference to sortAscending. Also, as far as changing the sorting dynamically, it looks like that is possible -- http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12476682/how-to-modify-the-sortproperties-value-dynamically-inside-an-ember-js-arraycontr

Answer (score 11):

I had the same problem. Took me a while, but eventually this general solution solved it:

```
App.ArrayController = Ember.ArrayController.extend({
  sortProperties: ['id'],
  sortAscending: true,

  sortedContent: (function() {
    var content;
    content = this.get("content") || [];
    return Ember.ArrayProxy.createWithMixins(Ember.SortableMixin, {
      content: content.toArray(),
      sortProperties: this.get('sortProperties'),
      sortAscending: this.get('sortAscending')
    });
  }).property("content.@each", 'sortProperties', 'sortAscending'),

  doSort: function(sortBy) {
    var previousSortBy;
    previousSortBy = this.get('sortProperties.0');
    if (sortBy === previousSortBy) {
      return this.set('sortAscending', !this.get('sortAscending'));
    } else {
      set('sortAscending', true);
      return this.set('sortProperties', [sortBy]);
    }
  }
});
```

Now most of my ArrayControllers extend `App.ArrayController` instead of `Ember.ArrayController`, in particular the ones that have Ember/Data `RecordArray`s as content.

Now, in your handlebar templates, do this:

```
 {{#each item in sortedContent}}
   ...          
 {{/each}}
```

instead of

```
 {{#each item in content}}
   ...          
 {{/each}}
```

Comment: I'm accepting this since it resolves my problem, but as Bradley Priest indicated above, binding to arrangedContent is sufficient.

Comment: Just a note, I found that using an ArrayController instead of an ArrayProxy w/ mixin worked for me.  I'm not sure what other side effects it has, but it works flawlessly. I have read that ArrayController is actually ArrayProxy with the mixins, but it doesn't seem to behave that way.

Answer (score 4):

I had a similar issue and sorted it out via the [docs for the array class](http://emberjs.com/api/classes/Ember.Array.html)
in my route I used the sortBy() method. so in your case it might be something like

```
App.store.findAll().sortBy('name');
```

I know this is an old question but answering it in case someone, like myself stumbles on by

Comment: `this.store.findAll('todo-list').sortBy('name')` is returning an empty array on my end, not sure why.

Comment: does removing the `sortBy()` make a difference? what property are you trying to sort by?

Comment: This is my code `var todoLists = this.store.findAll('todo-list').sortBy('name');`. If I remove the `sortBy()`, the results are correct. The Model I'm getting is https://github.com/LouWii/ember-todo-list-app/blob/master/app/models/todo-list.js (the whole project is on that Github repo actually).

Answer (score 3):

As of Ember version 1.0.0-rc.4  `Ember.ArrayProxy.create(Ember.SortableMixin ....` doesn't seem to work anymore. Use 
`Ember.ArrayProxy.createWithMixins(Ember.SortableMixin ....` or use the built-in sorting functionalities in Ember.ArrayController.